# Turn signal strangeness, and not just a burnt out bulb. 02 Safari Van

Tags: electrical, gmc, turn-signal

So for a couple weeks, I've had my right turn signals occasionally start blinking fast, but sometimes blinking at expected speed.  Because I could see the light of my front-right signal reflecting on the road (and blinking quickly), I assumed I had a burnt-out or loose rear bulb and picked a couple up last night to fix it.  Turns out I was wrong.  What I'm dealing with is:

- Left signals: everything is fine.
- Right-Front light: blinks fast
- Right dashboard light: blinks fast
- Right-rear light: Stays on solid when signal is on, off when not indicating.  (same with both the old and the new bulb)

Fuses look ok, but it was dark, so there is a chance I'm wrong on that.

What am I probably dealing with? What should I be checking?

**Note:**  Not a duplicate of [What would cause a solid turn signal indicator](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43283/what-would-cause-a-solid-turn-signal-indicator) as that is specifically a problem with the dashboard lite.  Not a duplicate of [Turn Signal Malfunctioning](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/turn-signal-malfunctioning?rq=1) as that appears to have been a burnt out bulb, which I have already ruled out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would cause a solid turn signal indicator?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43283/what-would-cause-a-solid-turn-signal-indicator)

Comment: @GdD added notes why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: What happens if you use the hazard switch does the signal light stay solid?

Comment: Are you equipped for towing? The front and rear lights are usually controlled by the same relay, so it isn't likely a relay issue. It's more likely that there is a short in the wiring at the rear, and there is often a separate relay unit in the rear for the trailer lights that is in line with your rear lights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it might be a faulty relay, you could try going into your fusebox and switching the relays for the left and right side lights (if applicable) or switching a different matching relay with the turn signal relay. If your problem switches from right to left or goes away completely, you know that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turn signal L and R circuits share the same blink relay. They blink too fast if the resistance in series with the blinker is too large (e.g. blown bulb). But if your bulbs are OK you need to investigate poor connection(s) in R hand circuit such as sockets, connectors, wiring. An ohmmeter and or voltmeter Wil be a big help.